# how to force reflow on the screen?

Tags: javascript, performance, browser

we know that some operations that calculating the style and layout will cause the performance bottleneck.
but how does the browser get it? see below

```
/*a: display: block in css*/
a.style.display = 'none'
console.log(a.offsetLeft);
/*do something*/
```

the value of `offsetLeft` will be `0` as expected;

but with that，if the `do something` cost too much time,

the element `a` will exist on screen util the `something` done.

why? and how to force reflow(`display:none`) on screen to .
thanks

Comment: The browser doesn't repaint while JS is executing. If you know the "do something" code takes too long, you can put it in a timeout with "no" delay, so that the current function will finish, the browser will repaint, then the timeout will run.

Comment: @nnnnnn but how does the `reflow`（offsetLeft -> 0）  done synchronously

Comment: Just because the repaint hasn't occurred yet doesn't mean the browser doesn't know the element has been removed from the flow with `display:none`.

Comment: that means the reflow occurred in webkit, but the reflow on screen occurred in gpu?